# PJSIP iOS5 Compilation Error

Tags: compiler-errors, ios5, pjsip

I am trying to compile the PjSIP from the source code using the `configure-iphone` script. I am able to run it, then run `make dep` without problems, but when I try to run `make` I have the following issues:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
    "_app_config_init_video", referenced from:
_app_init in pjsua_app.o
_console_app_main in pjsua_app.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjsua-arm-apple-darwin9] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pjsua] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I have tried changing to only armv6 but it didn't work. Any suggestions to compile it successfully??

Thanks!!

Comment: How did you get it to work could you post your findings as an answer sow we can see

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the configure-iphone script as described here:
http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2011-October/013481.html ?

That helped for me

Comment: Nop, it didn't worked out, the same error, I tried twice, one with the darwin9 and another with darwin 10:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm:
  "_app_config_init_video", referenced from:
      _app_init in pjsua_app.o
      _console_app_main in pjsua_app.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjsua-arm-apple-darwin10] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pjsua] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1